# How to fix .NET dll reference conflict?

Tags: c#, .net, c1-cms

I can run Composite C1 v4.0 Beta1 on Webmatrix. I tried to run it on VS2012 but I got a compiler error which one says these are 2 dll files for **System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult**

The code is:

```
 @helper NavigationTree(IEnumerable<PageNode> pages, int endRenderLevel)
```

I got two versions of System.Web.WebPages.dll:

- v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll
- v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll

Composite v4.0 /Bin folder also contains newer version. However I don't know how to point the correct dll, there are no Reference settings in the project, I just opened folder as website in VS2012.

How can I point the correct dll? I tried to add the correct dll reference but VS says reference is already added.

[image: dll-conflict.png]

Comment: where does the compiler error happen?

Comment: F5 run or F6 Build solution

Comment: if you have a global.asax file, try compile after excluding it.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly redirect (binding), as documented here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is probably a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

Just removed the older assembly reference from web.config

```
 <!-- <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> -->
```